# WPF: Button with custom template is not clickable as whole

Tags: c#, wpf, button, itemscontrol

I'm creating a simple WPF application for contacts managing in which I'm using an ItemsControl populated with customized button (see the code below) which I have stumbled upon an issue with.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ContactPreviewsCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Margin="0,5" CornerRadius="5" Background="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToBackgroundColorConverter}}">
                <Button Height="40" Cursor="Hand" Command="{Binding DataContext.ContactClickedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <StackPanel.Resources>
                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                        <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0"/>
                                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13"/>
                                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Light"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSalmon"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToForegroundColorConverter}}"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </StackPanel.Resources>

                                <TextBlock Width="200" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                <TextBlock Width="350" Text="{Binding Address}"/>
                                <TextBlock Width="100" Text="{Binding DateOfBirth}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This piece of code creates a list of contacts where the whole button area should be clickable (grey color). The problem is, that the only clickable areas are the TextBlocks contained inside the button (LightSalmon color). Screenshot here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hswye.png

So here comes my question: Is it possible to make the StackPanel inside the ControlTemplate clickable as a whole? I tried wrapping it in Border control but had no luck with that. I also tried searching here for similar issues but hasn't found anything.

PS: Don't worry about the horrible colors - I changed them to more apparent ones just for the purposes of this question :)

Comment: Set its Background, e.g. to Transparent.

Comment: Wow! That actually helped. In case that someone with a similar problem is reading this comment I would like to say that I also had to move the Height property from Button to StackPanel and set the VerticalAlignment of TextBlocks to Center. Now it works just fine so Thank you, @Clemens :)